# Regex to match 2 separated keywords in order

Tags: regex

#### Question

I'm trying to build a regular expression that matches a keyword ONLY if it comes sometime after another keyword.

In the following block of text, I want to match `Foo Client` **only** if it follows `Inactive Services` at any point.  Sometimes `Foo Client` can be under `Active Services`, in which case I do **NOT** want it to match.

Thanks!

#### Example Text:

```
Plugin Output:
Active Services :
Font Service [ FontService ] 
Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework [ wudfsvc ] 

Inactive Services :

Adobe Flash Player Update Service [ AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc ] 
Foo Client [ Foo Client ] 
App Readiness [ AppReadiness ]
```

Comment: Try `Inactive\sServices\s:\s+.*\s+\K(Foo\s+Client)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/q3x09o/1/)

Comment: I haven't tested this thoroughly which is why it is a comment, nor am I an expert in regex, but maybe this: `^(Inactive Services:){1}[\w\W\s]*(Foo Client){1}`. There are probably more efficient ways i'm not aware of

Comment: pkpkpk, yours did not work.

Comment: demogorgon.net, yours worked nearly perfectly, just had to add a space between Services and the colon.  Feel free to answer, or if you find a more elegant/efficient solution I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Inactive Services :[\w\W]*Foo Client` should work if I'm understanding your question properly. We just find the words 'Inactive Services' and then match any characters until finding Foo Client. We use `[\w\W]*` rather than .* since the dot does not match newlines.

```js
const pos = `Plugin Output:
Active Services :
Font Service [ FontService ] 
Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework [ wudfsvc ] 

Inactive Services :

Adobe Flash Player Update Service [ AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc ] 
Foo Client [ Foo Client ] 
App Readiness [ AppReadiness ]`;

const neg = `Plugin Output:
Active Services :
Font Service [ FontService ] 
Foo Client [ Foo Client ] 
Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework [ wudfsvc ] 

Inactive Services :

Adobe Flash Player Update Service [ AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc ] 
App Readiness [ AppReadiness ]`;

console.log(/Inactive Services :[\w\W]*Foo Client/.test(pos));
console.log(/Inactive Services :[\w\W]*Foo Client/.test(neg));
```